# Is a TPM device supposed to support both TPM1.2 and TPM2.0

Tags: tpm

I am using TPM device provided VMware Fusion.
The official documentation says that it [supports](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/11/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-317480E5-8478-4284-96DE-3B65387D1592.html) TPM 2.0.

Wiki says that TPM 1.2 and TPM 2.0 are [not compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module#TPM_1.2_vs_TPM_2.0).

I understand that it is probably a very silly question but nevertheless:

Does it mean that a chip supporting TPM 2.0 standard cannot operate in TPM 1.2 mode?

Comment: Correct. It's not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single TPM supporting both 1.2 and 2.0 is not mandated by TCG standard. I know Infineon's TPM supports either 1.2 or 2.0 but not 2-in-1; however, I cant say for others.